# what could be blocking port 5060 on my ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

I have a ubuntu 14.10, and am trying to telnet into it via port 5060 but I keep failing. I always get the message "Connection closed by foreign host".

I checked my iptable, it is default policy to ACCEPT, and ufw is inactive.

So I should be able to telnet into 5060 right? What else could be blocking it?

```
root@server:/var/log# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@server:/var/log# 

root@server:/var/log# ufw status
Status: inactive
root@server:/var/log#
```

but telneting just gives me this.

```
user@host ~
$ telnet 192.168.0.5 5060
Trying 192.168.0.5...
Connected to 192.168.0.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I want to run sip traffic on that port later but I can't even open the port right now.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you provided actually means that port `5060` is open and nothing is blocking it, because you got `Connected to 192.168.0.5`. But the connection got terminated by the destination host as soon as it was created, that's why it directly goes to `Connection closed by foreign host`. This is probably because the program that is listening on that port is expecting some data as soon as a connection was created, or maybe the program needs to be configured in a different way.

If a port is being blocked (or is not open), you will never see `Conneted to <IPaddress>`, but you'd see something like this:

```
Trying <IPaddress>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

You did the right thing by checking `iptables`, but since there are no rules blocking the traffic, you can further verify that the server in fact has port `5060` open by executing the following command:

```
netstat -ntlup | grep 5060
```

You should see an output like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Thanks Alaa, we found out that our sip application that is suppose to listen on 5060 is not listening on it for some reason. thanks for your help.